# PHP replace HTML elements with DIV

Tags: php, regex, html

I've been reorganising my code to be able to better support old IE browsers. I've put everything that is HTML5 only scripts in IF statements and it all works fine.

I just have one last change I need to make. I've collected all my site into an using `ob_start()` ... and would like to know the easiest way to replace all html5 elements like `article` with `div`. I was going to use `simplehtmldom` but I don't have `mb_character_encoding` so it doesn't work. To make it easier I've removed all comments and put all the code on one line in the hope of using a very shiny REGULAR EXPRESSION.

Comment: is necessary a regex when you only want plain text replace?

Comment: Have you considered using [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) instead?

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

- A simple replace, as suggested by Senad
- [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (not the easiest approach)
- OR... You can leave the HTML the way it is, and use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) on the client side to make older browsers recognize these elements, as well as a bunch of other HTML5/CSS3 features.

Comment: +1 for suggesting modernizr ... it's really the easiest way to force older browsers in recognising HTML5 tags

Comment: I'm using http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js but that's not really helping me that much. It's still crying and sending my elements in "random" places

Comment: I never used html5shiv, but modernizr worked perfectly for me (actually I just used it on one site, but it just worked).

Comment: I know its moving off topic a bit but why use modernizr? I'm using html5shiv because it seems to me the more widely used. What does modernizr have over html5shiv?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your `<article` with `<div`
and `</article>` with `</div>`

simple as that no need for complex regular expression

Comment: Except of course that he has to replace more than just the `article` tag. Hencewhy a single line of regex would be simpler (not to mention speedier) than 20 separate str_replace calls.

Comment: why 20? only 2 str_replace are needed, one for open tags and another for closings

Comment: Mario is right. I just pointed out article as an example. I would have to have 16 different str_replace calls.

Comment: its 2 str_replace not 20 and its faster than regex

Comment: Its 1 string replace call (remember, you can add arrays as arguments in the search & replace). Whether its faster: depends on circumstances. Whether its reliable: no it isn't, but with a trusted input you could get away with it.

Comment: Well yes. You can use the compact array call, but internally str_replace will iterate over the list, and rescan and modify the subject for each entry. Lots of `zval *tmp_result` copying. Why that's a suboptimal approach just to eschew a regex. Please profile, don't surmise.